# Explanation of syntax - is pygame.event.get() a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame

This is my explanation: pygame.event.get() returns a dictionary of queued events and event is an entry in the dictionary. Each event in the dictionary has a type and a key (amongst other attributes), and this is what we compare in the if statements.

pygame.QUIT and pygame.KEYDOWN are event types
pygame.K_RIGHT is an event key

Only if those events are in the queue will the corresponding code be executed

```
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    snake.move_snake_right()
```

It's analogous to picking up vegetables are the supermarket: there is a 'queue' of groceries waiting for you, each with a type, weight, best before date, etc. You will go through each one and only if it's type root vegetable and called parsnip will you pick it up.

Does anyone have a better explanation of dictionaries?

Also, why is it you call dictionaries like

```
Dictionary[Entry]
```

but here your calling

```
pygame.event.get().key
```

?

Comment: `pygame.event.get()` does not return a dictionary. It returns a list of `pygame.event.Event` objects

Answer (score 1):

> This is my explanation: pygame.event.get() returns a dictionary of queued events and event is an entry in the dictionary.

No. `pygame.event.get()` returns a list. You can check the source code yourself [here](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/main/src_c/event.c#L1533).

> Each event in the dictionary has a type and a key (amongst other attributes), and this is what we compare in the if statements.

Each event has a `type`, but not every event has a `key`.

Here's the list of all attributes for each event type:

```
QUIT              none
ACTIVEEVENT       gain, state
KEYDOWN           key, mod, unicode, scancode
KEYUP             key, mod
MOUSEMOTION       pos, rel, buttons
MOUSEBUTTONUP     pos, button
MOUSEBUTTONDOWN   pos, button
JOYAXISMOTION     joy (deprecated), instance_id, axis, value
JOYBALLMOTION     joy (deprecated), instance_id, ball, rel
JOYHATMOTION      joy (deprecated), instance_id, hat, value
JOYBUTTONUP       joy (deprecated), instance_id, button
JOYBUTTONDOWN     joy (deprecated), instance_id, button
VIDEORESIZE       size, w, h
VIDEOEXPOSE       none
USEREVENT         code
```

To quote the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html):

> All `pygame.event.EventType` instances contain an event type identifier and attributes specific to that event type. The event type identifier is accessible as the pygame.event.EventType.type property.

I suggest you read the linked document because it explains everything you need to know about events.

---

> Only if those events are in the queue will the corresponding code be executed

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                snake.move_snake_right()
```

The line `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` will be executed for each event that `pygame.event.get()` returned.

The next line (`if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:`) will only be executed if the `if` expression in the previous line returned a truthy value, which will only happen if the event we currently check has a `type` attribute that equals `pygame.KEYDOWN`.

And if the `key` attribute equals `pygame.K_RIGHT`, only then `snake.move_snake_right()` will be executed.

That has nothing to do with dictionaries. It's simply how looping with `for` and `if` statements work.

Comment: is pygame.key.get_pressed() a dictionary of all the keys with values True/False for if they are pressed?

Comment: Basically yes, but: `pygame.key.get_pressed` is a function that returns a `ScancodeWrapper`, which itself is a subclass of tuple. Since pygame's key constants (like `K_a` etc.) are numbers, they are used to access the elements of the `ScancodeWrapper`, since it's a tuple that looks like `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  ....., 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Nope its not a dictionary** But its an *iterable*(a list, tuple or something you can loop through)

**About Dictionaries**

Dictionaries are stored in key and value pairs.

For example

```
person = {"name": "Mickey", "age": 44}
```

**Accessing a value**

To access any of those values (Mickey or 44) you need to specify the correct key:

```
person["name"]
```

*Imagine 1000 rooms which have locked doors. To access whatever is in a particular room you need a key first(which unlocks the door).*

**Getting a list of all keys**

You can retrieve a list person keys like this

```
person.keys()
```

The you can iterate/loop it like these:

```
for k in person.keys():
    print(person[k])
```

*Imagine you had powers to pull all keys and instruct each of them to unlock the correct door*